# How to add a gradient to bottomNavigationBar?

Tags: flutter

How is it possible to add a gradient to the default bottomNavigationBar without a package?

```
    bottomNavigationBar: Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          gradient: LinearGradient(
              begin: Alignment.centerLeft,
              end: Alignment.centerRight,
              colors: [Colors.grey[600], Colors.grey[900]])),
      height: getBottomBarSize(),
      child: BottomAppBar(

          //color: Colors.grey[900],
          child: getChild()),
    ),
```

I tried this, but it doesn't work. Is there another way I could try without writing my own navBar or using a package?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because of the default behavior of `BottomAppBar` widget. You are not actually seeing your `Container` gradient because `BottomAppBar` color is hiding it.
Reverse your widgets order like this

```
bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
  child: Container(
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      gradient: LinearGradient(
        begin: Alignment.centerLeft,
        end: Alignment.centerRight,
        colors: [Colors.grey[600], Colors.grey[900]],
      ),
    ),
    height: getBottomBarSize(),
    child: getChild(),
  ),
),
```